# MS SQL for consecutive data with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table , looking for to not display consecutive duplicate 'AgentState' like below we have "Talking" @ 4:23:23 AM and 4:23:25 AM, we want to see single row data @ 4:23:23 AM with summed duration 00:00:35

```
Date Time                AgentState   ReasonCode    ReasonText   Duration
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:23 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:02
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:25 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:33
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:58 AM  Call Held        0                      00:00:38
Sep 27, 2017 4:24:36 AM  Talking          0                      00:01:01
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:37 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:00
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:37 AM  Call Held        0                      00:00:02
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:39 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:20
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:00
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM  Talking          11    Break            00:00:00
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM  Call Held        11    Break            00:00:15
Sep 27, 2017 4:26:14 AM  Not Ready        11    Break
```

Looking results as shown bellow

```
Date Time                AgentState   ReasonCode    ReasonText   Duration
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:23 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:35
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:58 AM  Call Held        0                      00:00:38
Sep 27, 2017 4:24:36 AM  Talking          0                      00:01:01
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:37 AM  Call Held        0                      00:00:02
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:39 AM  Talking          0                      00:00:20
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM  Call Held        11    Break            00:00:15
Sep 27, 2017 4:26:14 AM  Not Ready        11    Break
```

Could anyone help me ?

Best regards,

Vinod

Comment: choose any one of mysql and sql-server it refers different.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What's the data type of the `duration` column? It looks like `time` but using that to store a *duration* rather than a *time of day* can make some things problematic (notably, you can't record a duration > 24 hours)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date Time]),
        RN1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AgentState ORDER BY [Date Time]),
        * 
    FROM TheTable
)
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT 
        MIN(RN) RN, 
        CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,Duration)), '00:00:00') AS time) AS Duration 
    FROM 
        CTE
    GROUP BY 
     AgentState, (RN-RN1)
)
SELECT 
    CTE.[Date Time]
    ,CTE.AgentState
    ,CTE.ReasonCode
    ,CTE.ReasonText
    ,CTE2.Duration
FROM CTE2 INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE2.RN = CTE.RN 
ORDER BY  
    CTE.[Date Time]
```

Result:

```
Date Time                                          AgentState ReasonCode  ReasonText Duration
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------------
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:23 AM                            Talking    0           NULL       00:00:35.0000000
Sep 27, 2017 4:23:58 AM                            Call Held  0           NULL       00:00:38.0000000
Sep 27, 2017 4:24:36 AM                            Talking    0           NULL       00:01:01.0000000
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:37 AM                            Call Held  0           NULL       00:00:02.0000000
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:39 AM                            Talking    0           NULL       00:00:20.0000000
Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM                            Call Held  11          Break      00:00:15.0000000
Sep 27, 2017 4:26:14 AM                            Not Ready  11          Break      NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with calcs

as
(
Select groupNo, 
        min(datetime) as Datetime, 
        sum(
        ( DATEPART(hh, duration) * 3600 ) +
         ( DATEPART(mi, duration) * 60 ) +
         DATEPART(ss, duration)
          ) as Seconds
from
(
Select 

        datetime,
        row_number() over (order by [datetime])
        - row_number() over (partition by agentstate order by [datetime]) as GroupNo,
        duration

from talking
) a

group by groupNo
)


  Select t.datetime,
         t.agentState,
         t.reasonCode,
         t.reasonText,
         calcs.seconds

from talking t
inner join calcs on t.datetime = calcs.datetime

order by t.datetime
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1be76/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DateTime, AgentState, ReasonCode, ReasonText, Sum(Duration) AS Duration
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DateTime, AgentState, ReasonCode, ReasonText
ORDER BY DateTime
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Test this with other sample data and let me know

```
create table #t(Date_Time datetime,AgentState varchar(50),ReasonCode varchar(50)
, ReasonText varchar(50),Duration time)
insert into #t VALUES
('Sep 27, 2017 4:23:23 AM', 'Talking'  ,0 ,  null, '00:00:02')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:23:25 AM','Talking'  ,0 , null,  '00:00:33')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:23:58 AM','Call Held',0 , null,  '00:00:38')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:24:36 AM','Talking'  ,0 , null, '00:01:01')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:25:37 AM','Talking'  ,0 , null,  '00:00:00')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:25:37 AM','Call Held',0 , null,  '00:00:02')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:25:39 AM','Talking'  ,0 , null, '00:00:20')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM','Talking'  ,0 , null,  '00:00:00')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM','Talking'  ,11,'Break', '00:00:00')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:25:59 AM','Call Held',11,'Break' ,'00:00:15')
,('Sep 27, 2017 4:26:14 AM','Not Ready',11,'Break',null)
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
    FROM #t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,1 rn1
    FROM cte c
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.*
        ,cast(CASE 
                WHEN c.AgentState = c1.AgentState
                    THEN c1.rn1
                ELSE c1.rn1 + 1
                END AS INT) rn1
    FROM cte1 c1
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c1.rn + 1 = c.rn
    )
    ,cteMain
AS (
    SELECT rn1
        ,min(date_time) date_time
        ,(cast(sum(datepart(hour, duration)) AS VARCHAR) + 
        ':' + cast(sum(datepart(MINUTE, duration)) AS VARCHAR) + 
        ':' + cast(sum(datepart(second, duration)) AS VARCHAR)) TotalDuration
    FROM cte1 c
    WHERE c.Date_Time IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY rn1
    )

SELECT cm.Date_Time
    ,AgentState
    ,ReasonCode
    ,ReasonText
    ,cm.TotalDuration
FROM cteMain cm
INNER JOIN cte1 c ON c.rn1 = cm.rn1
    AND c.date_time = cm.date_time

DROP TABLE #t
```

> Alternative Solution

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
    FROM #t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,1 rn1
    FROM cte c
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.*
        ,cast(CASE 
                WHEN c.AgentState = c1.AgentState
                    THEN c1.rn1
                ELSE c1.rn1 + 1
                END AS INT) rn1
    FROM cte1 c1
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c1.rn + 1 = c.rn
    )


    SELECT rn1
        ,min(date_time) date_time
        ,min(AgentState) AgentState
        ,min(ReasonCode) ReasonCode
        ,min(ReasonText) ReasonText
        ,(cast(sum(datepart(hour, duration)) AS VARCHAR) + 
        ':' + cast(sum(datepart(MINUTE, duration)) AS VARCHAR) + 
        ':' + cast(sum(datepart(second, duration)) AS VARCHAR)) TotalDuration
    FROM cte1 c
    WHERE c.Date_Time IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY rn1

DROP TABLE #t
```